# logstash 5.1.2 : can't write output to csv file

Tags: logstash, etl, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I configure as follows

```
input {
   file{
      path => "/home/testfile/*"
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      codec => plain{
      charset => "ISO-8859-1"
   }
}

filter{
    grok{
        match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:test}"}
    }
}

output {
      csv {
          fields => ["@timestamp","message","test"]
          csv_options => {col_sep => "," row_sep => "\n"}
          path => "/home/testfile.csv"
}
```

But it seems the output file is not in the csv format (separate columns by "," , not write data by specify columns ) and file cannot be count by "wc -l" in linux (show 0 line, but when open in text editor. it can separate line and can open it)

What wrong with my configure? or logstash 5 change csv output plugin? because, with the same configure file. It works on logstash 2.3.4

Thank you in advance. and sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: this doesn't yet work on Logstash 5.x because of [this open issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-csv/issues/10). It should get fixed soon, but in the meantime this works on Logstash 2.4.

Comment: Thank you :) I able to find the workaround solution in that article too. that great.

The reason why i'm not using logstash 2.4 is because the data lost problem. and it seems logstash 5.x already fix this problem (the workaround solution bring back the problem to logstash 5.x. So i think it is the csv output plugin problem from the beginning )

Comment: Maybe comment that thread to inquiry about ETA for a fix...